# HTML background image insert

Tags: html, image, background

I am new into coding.
I am currently trying to build a personal website. When adding an background image, is adding it to a free image hosting service to get the url the only way to do this?
Or can I make it to where I can insert the image from my desktop files???
I have tried `<img src=` then adding the img jpg but doesn't seem to be working.
any tips?

Comment: If you can upload files including images, you can use one of your own. Alternatively upload the image to imgur and use that in the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<img>` tag `src` specifies the path to the image.

```
<img src="stackOverflow.jpg">
```

1. Image in Another Folder: If you have your images in a sub-folder, you must include the folder name in the `src` attribute.

   ```
   <img src="/images/hello.jpg">
   ```

   Here `/` is used to navigate inside sub-folder.
2. Images on Another Server/Website: To point to an image on another server,an absolute URL in the src attribute is used.

   ```
   <img src="abc.com">
   ```

To move to previous folder use `..`. Ex-

```
<img src="/images/hello.jpg">
```

Comment: so i did use <img src= "/downloads/rabidferret.jpg">

Comment: @MizzTech it depends where your image is located.